# MS Access - Auto populate cascading combobox if only one item

Tags: ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2010, cascadingdropdown

I have 4 cascading combo boxes linked to each other and they do exactly what I want them to do. However, I would like to take a shortcut with them and have them auto populate if they only have one list count.

I've already searched this and got a pretty good explanation from this link: [Access cascading combobox autofill When left with one option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184225/access-cascading-combobox-autofill-when-left-with-one-option)

However, I am making a webform and I do not have access to VBA. How can I translate the VBA into a macro?

I imagine it's some type of "IF" option, like if the list count in combobox2 = 1, then do something. I just don't know what that something would be.

Comment: Possibly the 'something' would be SetValue. Click "Show All Actions" on the ribbon.

Comment: And considering it's a cascading form, what would I set the value to?

Comment: I don't use macros so did some exploring. Appears combobox properties Column and ItemData and ListCount are not available. This simply might not be possible with macro. Users will just have to select item even if there is only one.